# Create Polyline feature in Z M Enabled Featureclass

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop

I want to create a polyline feature in Z M enabled featureclass.

```
Point1.x= 1000
Point1.Y = 1100
Point1.Z = 1200

PointCollection.addpoint Point1
Point2.x= 5000
Point2.Y = 5100
Point2.Z = 5200
PointCollection.addpoint Point2
```

But when I try to store feature as `Feature.shape = Pointcollection` it is giving this error: `Item not found in the collection`.

Comment: What is the error message? That will help solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Item not found in the collection

Comment: To be able to answer this question we need to see the rest of your code, for example what is pointCollection, your addpoint method is in lower case which would suggest to me that you have declared this incorrectly?